# how to check if its been 10 seconds or more than 10 seconds when web page is inactive?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can we set in javascript or jquery for example:

```
time = 0; //0 second
// and time will start by 1 second to infinite second
if(time <= 10) {  // 10 is 10 second here
    alert("abc");
} else {
    alert("xyz");
}
```

Suppose web page is loaded and time should increment by 1 second and when it has been 10 second it should alert abc and when more than 10 second it should alert xyz

**The whole process should run automatically when page is loaded not by clicking on start and end button**

Please help me to find it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when will you check for the time and when do you start to count the time?

Comment: @Danial_Abzadough Suppose web page is loaded and time should increment by 1 second and when it has been 10 second it should alert abc and when more than 10 second it should alert xyz